# Least value of magnitude of a vector

Tags: vectors

Suppose a and b are vectors such that $a \times b = 2i + j - k$ and 
$a+b= i - j + k$. The least value of magnitude of vector $a$ is ?

Here $i$, $j$ and $k$ are unit vectors in direction of $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes and $\times$ symbolizes cross product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $a\times b=u$ and $a+b=v$ then  $a\times(v-a)=a\times v=u$.

Comment: But how do I find the minimum of a?

Answer (score 1):

If $a\times b=u$ and $a+b=v$ then $a\times(v−a)=a\times v=u$.
$(a1,a2,a3)\times(1,-1,1)=(a2+a3,a3-a1,-a1-a2)=(2,1,-1)$.
Find one solution, $a_0=(a1,a2,a3)$, to $a\times v=u$.  The general solution will be $a_0+kv=(a1+k,a2-k,a3+k)$.
Write $|a_0+kv|^2$ as a function of $k$.  It will be a quadratic.  Find the minimum value of the quadratic.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but I still not able to solve the equations for the cross product. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

$ a \times b = 2i+j-k$ and $a+b = i-j+k $

So $a \times(i-j+k-a)=2i+j-k$, so $a \times (i-j+k)=2i+j-k$

Let $a = xi+yj+zk$

putting on above equation and finding cross product and comparing coefficients we get $x+y=1$,$y+z=2$,$z-x=1$.

The required answer is $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$  using above 3 relations and eliminating  $y$ and $z$ we get $(3x^2+2)^{1/2}$. The minimum value of a square of a number is 0(considering real and excluding complex numbers) so the answer is $2^{1/2}$ or $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Your answer is very hard to read. I'd suggest that you visit the page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for information on how to properly format your equations.

Comment: Please, note that @BigbearZzz is right. Your answer was very hard to read due to poor formatting. I edited your answer to improve the formatting.